# Is it possible? Linksys SPA VoIP PHONE push VLAN id in DHCP

Tags: asterisk, dhcp, linksys

Is it possible to push VLAN information in DHCP message for Linksys phones?

I have sitches with untagged data VLAN and tagged VLAN for phones, but with no CDP or LLDP support.

I want to push provisioning to phones from IP PBX (asterisk) which is in Voice VLAN.

Polycom phones has that functionality (DHCP option (string) 128 which which should have value "VLAN-A=77;" for example) than phone after it receives dhcp information reconfigures ethernet port to VLAN 77.

I'm looking for simmilar functionality for linksys SPA phones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution for this case is to make tftp server availble from data VLAN.
in defaul config file you have to add statement:

```
 <Enable_VLAN>Yes</Enable_VLAN>
<VLAN_ID>77</VLAN_ID>
```

unfortunatly phone after receiving that file doesn't reboot so you have to reboot it manually (for examle toggle on/off PoE on switch)

77 - voice VLAN ID in my case please feel with your setting

Answer (score 0):

Linksys  ask vlan via CDP protocol. So that will work only if your switch is linksys or cisco.

```
Enable CDP
only if you are using a Linksys
switch. CDP is negotiation based and
determines which VLAN the SPA9X2 resides in.
```

Comment: I have sitches with untagged data VLAN and tagged VLAN for phones, but with NO CDP or LLDP support.